# How do I change the value of an input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to "override/overwrite" an input element fixed value using javascript and/or jquery?

i.e. if i have an input element like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" name="inputs" value="someValue" />
</div>
```

is it possible to make a jquery object of that element and then change its value to something else then rewrite the jquery object to the dom??
I'm trying but obviously I haven't got good results!

I've been trying something like this:

```
$('input').val("someOtherDynamicValue");
var x = $('input');
$("#myDiv").html(x);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are accomplishing. If you want to simply change the value, why would you need to rewrite the entire element?

Comment: @Lina, could you please explain what you are trying to do with the input field and perhaps a clearer solution may resolve. :)

Comment: when i alert the input element after changing its value (i.e. after the first line of code) i find out that its value is still "someValue" and not "someOtherDynamicValue", that is why i'm trying to rewrite the entire element. this issue is killing me... any solution please???

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access the value via the `$.val()` method:

```
$("[name='inputs']").val("Foo"); // sets value to foo
```

Without needing to re-insert it into the DOM. Note the specificity of my selector `[name='inputs']` which is necessary to modify only one input element on the page. If you use your selector `input`, it will modify *all* input elements on the page.

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/imuzo3/edit

Comment: @Lina The above code does work with the HTML you provided. Please see my demo link in the post above.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to manipulate the value of the input element, use the first line of your code. However it will change the value of every input element on the page, so be more specific using the name or the id of the element.

```
$('input[name=inputs]').val("someOtherDynamicValue");
```

Or if the element had an id

```
$('#someId').val('some Value');
```

Check out jQuery's selectors (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to see how to get whatever element you need to manipulate with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

//Changes on the load of form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourTxtBoxID').val('newvalue');
});
```

//Changes on clicking a button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#somebuttonID').click(function(){
    $('#yourTxtBoxID').val('newvalue');
});
});
```